# Why did my POST request gets split into two pieces

Tags: c++, sockets, post, split, http-headers

I want to login into a Website with my C++ program. I created a http class to send my POST Request over sockets.
But when is send my Request it gets split right at the end of the Header:

First Packet:

```
POST /api/user/login HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: myhost.com\r\n
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 \r\nFirefox/36.0\r\n
Accept: text/*\r\n
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3\r\n
Charset: UTF-8\r\n
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n
Referer: http://myhost.com/\r\n
Content-Lenght: 29\r\n
Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n
<-- gets cut off here -->
```

And the POST data is transmitted in another TCP packet.

I tried to copy the POST request from my browser and its absolutely identical. But I don't get the cookies from the login with my program. It only works on my Browser where my Packets did not get split.

I also checked my MTU but that is set to 1500 and I only transmit around 500 Byte.

Can I prevent my request getting split?

Comment: TCP is a *streaming* protocol, there is no real beginning and there is no real end. There's especially no fixed packet sizes.

Comment: Yes I was thought the same but after trying the whole day to get one POST request working I dont think that anymore. I have also a TCP Stream of both the Browser and my program: http://www.mediafire.com/view/0da9qr5id3zczh0/Unbenannt.PNG
Left I got the Cookies from the Server and on the right my program does not get them. But it is the same request with this little difference, that my packets got split always directly after the header.

Comment: I got it.......I have miswritten the "Content-Length"... And therfor i searched the whole day...

Comment: With TCP you have to read until you know you have all data in a loop. The way to know if you have all data for HTTP is to know when the headers end, and use the `Content-length` header.